# Google scripts marking message as read not working

Tags: google-apps-script

In my google script I read a message, and then i mark it as read.
I can get all information from my message (subject, body etc), but a couple of lines further, when I try to make my message read, it doesn't work

```
GmailApp.markMessageRead(message);
message.markRead();
var a = message.isUnread();
message.star();
message.reply("Henkiepenkiepankie");
```

var a returns false, so the message is read. The weird thing is that the message has a star in gmail and a reply is sent too

Answer (score 0):

It randomly started working after not changing anything